# error: Reference to type 'iconventionrelationshipbuilder' claims it is defined in 'microsoft.entityframeworkcore', but it could not be found

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

net Core and EF core. While trying to build the application and launch I am getting the error mentioned - error: Reference to type 'iconventionrelationshipbuilder' claims it is defined in 'microsoft.entityframeworkcore',  but it could not be found.

Kindly guide as I could not find the solution for the following error.

Comment: Hi @HarieshRK, Try to right click the project and choose the clean option, then rebuild the project and check whether the error disappear or not? Besides, can you explain more detail about your error:  Which version of Asp.net Core and EF core version are you using? Have you ever added any class library or package? If possible, you could share the detail steps to reproduce, then, we can work together to figure it out.

Comment: Hi there, I cleaned and built the application. It was still throwing error. I am using .NET core 3 and EF core 5. I also installed EF core sql server 3 and ef core tools 3. I added because I wanted to do DB first approach. The issue is occuring in context.cs file when there is a foreign key reference to another table

Answer (score 4):

Did you by any chance try scaffolding an MVC Controller with view, using Entity Framework?

Apparently that downgrades EF Core SqlServer and Tools to 3.1.15
My problem was solved by upgrading it back to 5.0.5

Answer (score 2):

As Habedi said, when you are trying to scaffold MVC controller with view, using Entity Framework program uses

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration version="3.1.5"
```

for the scaffold process. Problem is, that package is referencing EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and EntityFrameworkCore.Tools both in the 3.1.15 version, so it automatically downgrades those packages and they are unable to process dbcontext code generated with futher versions as 5.0.5.

My solution was to delete my dbcontext and autogenerate another with EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and EntityFrameworkCore.Tools both in the 3.1.15 version, then I tried to scaffold and had no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It is correct, that the packages are downgraded. So go just in the NuGet-Manager and update everything you can (EF core & EF core sql Server & EF Core tools). I cant update "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design", but it still works.